# How to test multiple sites in django project using sites framework/multiple settings

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a project that shares a database among many wsgi apps (sites framework from contrib is in heavy use). Each wsgi app has it's own module in project dir with it's own settings.py that extend `global_settings.py` in main project dir (each settings file simply imports * from global_settings). Also some sites have their own urls and extra views/templates that cannot be tested globally. All the sites share most apps though. Also due to customisations of views (subclassed cbl views) I need to test each site separately. Django expects `tests.py` only in app dirs so I can't issue:

```
./manage.py test first_site --settings=first_site.settings
```

since `first_site` is just a python module not a django app. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm only starting multisite testing and came up with a primitive solution for now:

```python
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(SITE_ID=1)
def test_multisite_one(self):
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    self.assertEqual(1, Site.objects.get_current().id)
```

Comment: So many years later, you saved my day! This `@override_settings` is perfect to perform tests against different sites in the same test suite.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-discover-runner

After installing django-discover-runner (in pip for example):

```
pip install -U django-discover-runner
```

You just need to add one line to custom site settings:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'discover_runner.DiscoverRunner'
```

and this command will run tests from normal python module called `first_site`

```
./manage.py test first_site --settings=first_site.settings
```

Seems legit.